# Vc++ 2012 Express on Windows XP

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-xp

I was very happy to learn that Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop has recently been released.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673

But then I discovered that I cannot use it, apparently. I am still on XP as I can't afford an upgrade at this time, and the tools simply do not install. I have 2008 and 2010 installed which seems to work okay, but not 2012 for whatever reason.

Basically, I only need the compiler (not the Visual Studio IDE). I use CodeBlocks as my IDE. Does anyone know if it is possible to install and use the compiler only? I would very much like to use C++11 with the new optimizations that it brings.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Earlier in June of this year, Microsoft announced that it will stop support to win XP in April 2014, and I don't think they will spend unnecessary effort in legacy environment. (But that is my take on it)

Comment: During the development of VS 2012, it was announced that XP would not be supported - not just the IDE but the executables produced as well. They changed their mind on the executables but I don't think there's anything that could move them on the rest of the package.

Comment: The 2012 Express edition only supports developing Windows Store apps.  Which requires Windows 8.  They will keep the 2010 Express edition available so you can still target XP and desktop apps.

Comment: @HansPassant: Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop has just been released, and it supports building desktop applications.  See http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-delivers-vs-express-2012-toolkit-for-building-windows-8-desktop-apps-7000004157/

Comment: Thanks, hot off the press.  But of course no XP support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the compiler is just the [.NET framework](http://www.microsoft.com/net) or at least that is what I understand that SharpDevelop uses to compile its code.  So, my guess is that Visual Studio 2012 is using .NET 4.5, which means that your out of luck when it comes to running on XP.  Microsoft has started to end its life cycle.

Comment: ...except .NET framework 4.5 [is not supported on Windows XP either](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is *not* supported in WinXP. It is official from microsoft. [Visual Studio Software Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673#system-requirements)

Comment: ...and the Windows 7 SDK has VS2010 compilers, not VS2012.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson.  From what I can find it doesn't look like the Windows 7 SDK has changed any for VS2012, just the .NET framework.  Even so Steven is right and it isn't possible at the current time.

Comment: @TravisPessetto It is not about the Win7 SDK. The OP asked about how to install VS2012 (or the C++ compiler, for that matter) in WinXP. He is not concerned (as far as i know) about the Win 7 SDK. VS2012 is designed to **not run** on WinXP. Period!

Comment: @Steven just in case you didn't notice.  I've updated the answer.  I forgot to check if .NET was XP compatible earlier. Also, I will remove the last link to Windows 7 SDK.